# Why is Rails saving the session even if there have not been any changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord

My Rails (3) application uses AJAX to load a few portlets on a dashboard. The user has to be authenticated to be able to view the dashboard. So the user_id stored in the session is important. I am using the default ActiveRecord session store.

After the GET '/dashboard' completes, several XHR GET requests fire (and are handled parallel b/c of load balancing). These requests do not modify the session in any way, they just retrieve the user_id from the session.

Still, this results in a `UPDATE 'sessions' ... where 'session.id' = ...` for every XHR request. Causing a row lock in the first XHR request, so following XHR requests hang until the lock is released.

Is there any reason Rails should save the session again to the database, even if there have not been any changes?

Answer (score 0):

Rails updates the `updated_at` field, so you can see when the session was last *used*.

For example, you might throw away sessions that haven't been used for some time. Doing a request means you're using the session.